# What should be the value of x?

Tags: javascript

what value should X have so this condition would work?

```
// insert code here
if (x == 1 && x === 2) {
     console.log('Succes!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick ([Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3zax/1/)):

```
x = {};
x.valueOf = function (){
    x = 2; // this is important
    return 1;
};

if (x == 1 && x === 2) {
    console.log('Success !!!');
}
```

**Explanation:**
The statements are executed from left to right (so first `x == 1`, then `x === 2`). When checking `x == 1`, it will go to the `valueOf` function, which returns `1`, so it will be true. But at the same time, `x` is changed to be `2`, thus the next statement that will be checked (`x === 2`) will also be true.

**PS:** As far as I know, this has no practical application. However, it can lead to better understanding of how javascript works - which is the point of such questions :)

Answer (score 4):

X should be defined like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(window,'x',{
    get: function() {
        this.__tmp = this.__tmp || 2;
        this.__tmp = 3-this.__tmp;
        return this.__tmp;
    }
});
```

Then:

```
if( x == 1 && x === 2)
```

MIGHT work. [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/aK9p7/)

Comment: Nice usage of javascript properties. However it should be noted it will only do the trick if the user calls `(x == 1 && x === 2)` without using `x` beforehand (or every time he calls it after an even number of `x` accesses)

Comment: @vdavid Correct - which is why it only "might" work XD Unfortunately there's no way for the getter to know the context of being got...

Comment: @FranciscBoicu No. There is not. At least, none that I can think of. However possibly you could define `window.x` as a wrapper for "get a random number in a given range" or some other function that doesn't return a constant value.

Comment: I was wondering if we could define a different property for the implicit conversion and the plain value, but if I do something like `Object.defineProperty(window,'x',{ get: function() {return 2;}, toString:function(){return "1";} });` (or many other variants including `value`, `valueOf`, etc.) there is always a single property that is used. But maybe I haven't tried the good ones…

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no such value.

`x === 2` checks if `x` equals *exactly* to `2`, while `2` cannot be `1` at the same time.

Only the following would make sense:

```
if (x && x === 2) { ... }
```

(or getter overloading, as demonstrated in [@Niet the Dark Absol's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104948/1249581) answer, which is not a pure case)

Answer (score 1):

X can't hold a value equals to 1 and identical to 2 at the same time, this expression is logically incorrect.

Comment: That is true, although it was a javascript question, not necessarily a logical question (I edited the question to remove the `logic` tag).

Answer (score 1):

Using `===` (identity) operator it will never work, but it's possible to construct an object that will be "equal" (`==`) to 1 and 2 at the same time:

```
x = { valueOf: function() { return this.foo ? 2 : this.foo = 1 } }
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2) // true
```

"valueOf" is the method JS implicitly calls when you convert or compare an object to a number.

Needless to say, this exercise doesn't have any practical sense.