# Html entities manipulated with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

I'm having issues in a formular with some htmlentities in the value attributes:

```
<form>
  <input name="my-text" type="text" value="hello &amp; world">
</form>
//Display in my input "hello & world"`
```

Now if I update the value of my input with this script:

```
<script>
  document.getElementsByName("my-text").item(0).value = "hello &amp; world";
</script>
// Display in my input "hello &amp; world"`
```

How can display "hello & world" even when value is update by javascript? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are updating same value "hello &amp; world" ... can you please clear what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`&amp;`** is a HTML entities so its rendering without quotes.

But in your case you have to show & sign into string so you must have to write **`&`** sign by your self do not need to write **`& sign HTML code (&amp;)`**.

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCy8y/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer was pretty simple. I also figured out that it doesn't if I forgot to declare the meta: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the html entities when setting the value through JavaScript.

```
document.getElementsByName("my-text").item(0).value = "hello & world";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't escape it: `[...].value = "hello & world";`

Escaping HTML entities only needs to be done in an HTML context - otherwise you'd be writing stuff like [`if( x == 1 &amp;&amp; x === 2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104948/507674)!

In general, you should be aware of the context of where your stuff is.